# Host unreachable EHOSTUNREACH error

Tags: android, sockets

I have developed an app that has been running fine on a Acer Tab with Android OS 4.1.2 with Kernel 3.4.0 and a Samsung Tab with 4.1.2 and 3.0.31. The app opens a TCP socket with a destination address and port.

The same app does not run on a newer Acer Tab (same model) with the same OS and Kernel versions or a new Lenovo Tab again with the same OS and Kernel versions. It reports the following error on creating a Socket with a dest addr and a dest port:
libcore.io.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)

I updated the app from target SDK 15 to 16 but the same problem persists - same app continues to run fine on the two older devices but not on the two new devices.

Before creating the Socket if I check isConnected() on the NetworkInfo object accessed through the ConnectivityManager it returns true.

Would appreciate any pointers to what I should explore next.

Comment: can u provide your Logcat

Comment: You are connecting via wifi? Do other network apps (web browser etc) work fine on these newer devices?

Comment: u sure u hav internet connection in that device